# Load iframe only once with toggle event

Tags: jquery, events, load, toggle

I have this code which loads and display's iframe which is display:hidden in default:

```
   $("div").on('click', '.blok', function () { 

  $(this).siblings("iframe").toggle().show().attr("src", $(this).siblings('span').find('a').attr('href') );

    });
```

As you can see I have put .toggle so that a second click would restore to default values. The problem is that the second click also LOADS the iframe again (while it is hidden). What can I do to load only once in the toggle event?

Comment: I put the toggle in which I forgot..

Comment: you should probably share the part of code which involves iframe

Comment: @Dhiraj Bodicherla Just a simple html iframe, nothing fancy <iframe></iframe>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the attr('src'..) should only be called once (or every time you want to load the page)

i'd leave the toggle there but put the attr outside the function

Comment: How do I do that with only one button (.blok)..??

Comment: Never mind, stupid question I realize now...:) Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you put the iframe into some other component and toggle it's visibility instead of the iframe itself? This way you wouldn't be touching the iframe and that shouldn't cause any reload of it.

Answer (score 1):

Load the iframe only if href in link is same as iframe src, else just toggle

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/dhirajbodicherla/r2h4q/)

Hope this helps